# Understanding will paginate scopes/relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Why does Post.page(1).total_pages result in:

```
Post.page(1).total_pages
undefined local variable or method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000006a95230>
```

but

```
Post.scoped.page(1).total_pages
```

works fine. Curiously,

```
Post.paginate(:page => 1).total_pages
```

works fine. I looked at the code on Github ( https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb ) and I can see why paginate works (because it calls limit first... which returns an active record relation, much like scoped does). I have a feeling it has something to do with this code

```
rel = scoped.extending(RelationMethods)
```

I guess I don't understand the difference between these the active record relation that limit returns versus scoped.extending(RelationMethods). Any ideas?

Comment: does this work: `Post.page(1).all.total_pages`

Comment: What versions of Rails and will_paginate are you using? I can't replicate this.

Comment: @apneadiving no, still get undefined method.

Comment: @MattSanders Rails 3.1.1 and will_paginate 3.0.2
I'll keep digging....

Comment: @MattSanders hmm I also could not replicate this on a brand new rails app. My app is very new and isn't that big, so I'll see if I can find the reason/difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens when using the rails_admin gem. It works fine in a fresh Rails 3.1.1 app with will_paginate 3.0.2.

Rails admin is probably doing something to the page method, though I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: As a final update, rails_admin includes the kaminari gem for its paging. So, somehow that is interfering with will_paginate. Github issues for each project has some mentions of not working together perfectly, so I just settled on using kaminari in my project as well.